# Java 11 module + Weld

Tags: java, weld, module-info

I created a simple Java 11 SE maven project with Weld 3.0.5.

```
package main;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();
        try (SeContainer container = initializer.initialize()) {
           A a =  container.select(A.class).get();
           a.say();
         }
    }
}
```

Everything was fine but when I added to my project module-info.java file, weld stops working.

```
module glowny {
    requires weld.se.shaded;
    opens main to weld.se.shaded;
}
```

**Exception:**

> Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException:
>   WELD-001524: Unable to load proxy class for bean Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] with qualifiers [@Default] with class interface javax.enterprise.inject.Instance using classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2ed94a8b
>       at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: Weld is not modularized ATM and I am not sure what happens when you put a shaded non-modularized JAR on module path. What you could do is instead use Weld dependency which isn't shaded. But that would require a lot more magic on your module-info as you will need to open your modules to several weld modules for deep reflection.

Comment: There is also bits and pieces of information about Weld and JMPS in this JIRA issue, feel free to contribute your findings please - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2493